# How to get a specific action from the HTMLEditorKit?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, htmleditorkit

I want to create a simple test application with a [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) displaying some HTML content and a button which makes the selected text bold. The [HTMLEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) already provides the necessary action for this button so I was able to use it with complicated code like this:

```
// Build action map
Map<String, Action> actionMap = new HashMap<String, Action>();
for (Action action: editor.getActions())
    actionMap.put("" + action.getValue(Action.NAME), action);

// Get the action
Action action = actionMap.get("font-bold");
```

But I'm pretty sure there is something wrong. I can't believe that I have to create this helper map to get the action by name. The only official method I found for retrieving the actions seems to be this [getActions()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getActions%28%29) method of [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) which just returns an array.

So is there a better way to fetch a specific action from an `EditorKit` and I simply missed it or is it just bad API design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you fill your own map?

```
editor.getActionMap().allKeys()
editor.getActionMap().get("font-bold")
```

Comment: Just to make it clear for other passers-by, `editor` here refers to the JEditorPane instance. Also, the constructor `StyledEditorKit.BoldAction()` can be used to the same end.